# Template definition of non-template after introducing typetraits

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

I have a `ServiceLocator` class. It worked fine, but I wanted to add a type trait, that the `ServiceLocator` must use a Service-Type which extends some `BaseService` class. My `BaseService` class has some properties I want every service to have, like being non-copyable. So let's see my code:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include "BaseService.hpp"

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseService, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class ServiceLocator {
private:
    ServiceLocator() {}
    static std::unique_ptr<T> service;
public:
    static void provide(std::unique_ptr<T> service) {
        ServiceLocator::service = std::move<>(service);
    }
    static T &getService() {
        return *(ServiceLocator::service.get());
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> ServiceLocator<T>::service;
```

This code isn't that magical. But I get the following error:

> ServiceLocator.hpp:22:39: error: template definition of non-template
>   ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp>ServiceLocator::service’  std::unique_ptr
>   ServiceLocator::service;

Like I said, my `BaseService` class isn't that special, but for completeness:

```
#pragma once

#include "NonCopyable.hpp"

class BaseService : private NonCopyable {
};
```

NonCopyable:

```
#pragma once

class NonCopyable {
public:
    NonCopyable() {}
private:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

It is working if I remove the type trait part of my template, so if i remove this part:

```
, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseService, T>::value>::type* = nullptr
```

I tried to make the `unique_ptr` of fixed type: `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>` and work with `static_cast` in my two methods. But couldn't get that to work. 
The only thing that is want is that type `T` must extend my `BaseService`.

Comment: Also, `std::move<>(...)` is not a thing. Just `std::move(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is working if i remove the typetrait part of my template, so if i remove this part:

That should have been a strong hint as to what's wrong (side-note: that isn't a type-trait, it's a constraint). The problem is, you're class template declaration is, ignoring defaults:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseService, T>::value>::type*>
class ServiceLocator { ... };
```

That is, it takes **two** template parameters: one type, one non-type. Your out-of-class static definition is:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> ServiceLocator<T>::service;
```

That's **one** template parameter. That's just not a thing. You can't rely on defaults here, because the static member needs to be defined for the non-default cases as well.

The solution here is just to move your constraint into the body - since as a template parameter I don't think it solves anything for you:

```
template <typename T>
class ServiceLocator {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<BaseService, T>);
    // ...
};
```

And now you just have the one template parameter, so no problems.

---

Note that after C++11, you don't need `NonCopyable` anymore, you can just explicitly delete special member functions:

```
struct BaseService {
    BaseService() = default;
    BaseService(BaseService const&) = delete;
    BaseService& operator=(BaseService const&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: You saved me :) Thanks for your great answer. Just for completeness, it is "static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseService, T>::value);", you missed the "::value" at the end. Tank you alot :) One small question, your BaseService-struct is exactly what my NonCopyable is. I just made an extra class because i can use this on more than my BaseService. So i see no advantage in your version of BaseService. Is there something i don't see?

Comment: @Schorsch No, I didn't. C++17 has an [`is_base_of_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of), which is a variable template of type bool.